# Change user and group of android app files to replicate issue user is having

Tags: android, shell, adb

I have an android app on the market and one of my users has reported a problem which nobody else has had (at least as far as I am aware of). They've told me what they did and what settings they had used as well as android version they are using so I am trying to replicate it as much as possible.

I install the original app before the update (when everything was working fine) and set up in the same way as the user said they had. I have then gone into the shell and gone into `/data/data/com.mycompany.myapp/` and checked the `databases` and `shared_prefs` folder to check the ownership and both files were set up to be and the user and group are both set up to be `app_36`. I then pulled all the contents onto my development PC so that I have the database and prefs file.

I have then uninstall the original and installed the new version of the app by using `adb install`com.mycompany.myapp`I then upload the databases and prefs file using`adb push`` and then viewed the permissions of the file using the adb shell and can see that they are now owned by root so the app can't access those file. I have then tried, from the adb shell doing the following:

```
adb shell
cd com.mycompany.myapp/shared_prefs
chown app_36:app_36 prefs.xml
```

This would work in normal linux changing the user and group to be app_36 but its saying that there is no user app_36:app_36. However, if I do chown app_36 prefs.xml it then changes the owner fine but I can't change the group.

To change the group I've use chgrp app_36 prefs.xml but it then says chgrp not found.

How can I change the user and the group so that I can copy the files over and replicate the issue my user is having.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: I would remove the original prefs.xml file and replace it by user's file. Also you can edit file system by DDMS in eclipse or in the sdk/tools folder.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use dot as a delimiter:

```
chown app_36.app_36 prefs.xml
```

Comment: Many Many thanks. Unable to proceed for hours before i saw your answer.